# Why is JPA / Hibernate slowing down when loading a large amount of data in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

When using Spring Data in a RestCall there is a Session in which Hibernate is caching Data. Loading a new Entity inside one RestCall causes Hibernate to caching this Entity while until the RestCall is completed. When loading a lot of Data Sprng significantly slows down because the Hibernate is acumulating more Data. The Java Entity is not garbe colledted since Hibernate still has a reference to it.

In the following Code the first ~100 Entities are processed as expected. Afterwards the Execution in this RestCall slows down increasingly. The question now is why does this slow the RestCall Code execution down. There is enough RAM available ane even if there would not be I would expect an OOM to be thrown. Why is it getting slower? The Number of elements is less than 1500 and should not be a Problem for Java/Spring.

```
        public void someMethodCalledFromRestController() {
          List<String> allRelevantNumbers = someService.findNumbers();
          for (String number : allRelevantNumbers) {
              List<Customers> customersGroup = someService.findActiveCustomersByNumber(number); // includes a repository.find(); method
              this.workOnCustomerGroup(customersGroup);
          }
        }

        ....


        public void workOnCustomerGroup(List<Customers> customersGroup) {
        try {
            LocalDateTime startWorkTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            Result result = someService.doSomeWork(customersGroup);
            resultService.createResult(result); // includes repository.save();

//            entityManager.clear();
//            Map.Entry<Object, EntityEntry>[] entries = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class).getPersistenceContext().reentrantSafeEntityEntries();

            log.info("Work took " + ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startWorkTime, LocalDateTime.now()) +
                    " ms. ");
         catch ( ...
```

The corresponding Log shows that the performance is degrading with time.

```
2023-03-27 08:29:37.904  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 352 ms. 
2023-03-27 08:29:38.338  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 384 ms. 
2023-03-27 08:29:38.748  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 357 ms. 
2023-03-27 08:29:39.133  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 354 ms. 
....
2023-03-27 08:37:54.978  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 2685 ms.
2023-03-27 08:37:57.695  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 2699 ms.
2023-03-27 08:38:00.472  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 2745 ms.
2023-03-27 08:38:03.211  INFO 12084 --- [io-12710-exec-1] Work took 2726 ms.
```

Using entityManager.clear(); solves the the performance issue. The following line shows that the Hibernate Context is growing in size without entityManager.clear();. There are explicitly no Transactions used in this example.

Comment: I suggest you read up on batch processing with hibernate and also learn what the session actually is and what hibernate does.

Answer (score 9):

This question warrants a slightly more detailed explanation, as what you run into is both influenced by the way that JPA works as well as the default configuration Spring Boot uses to accommodate common web application use cases.

### Context

Spring Boot's default configuration setup for JPA assumes that web requests can usually be answered by loading a couple to a hundred entities or might trigger some state transitions and render some kind of representation (JSON / HTML) as a result. It registers an `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` that opens up a single `EntityManager` instance that's used by all repository interactions. This allows that in all stages of the request processing, entities can be accessed as exposed by their types. Some relationships those entities might be backed by lazy relationships that require additional database lookups on access. With the configuration defaults chosen, the result rendering (Jackson for JSON or something like Thymeleaf for HTML) will be able to use the JPA managed entities, without exposing the lazy nature of those relationships to developers. This provides the convenience of them not having to deal with it for standard use cases.

### Problem

Use cases, such as yours, that deviate from that model would actually benefit from a different tradeoff, as the single `EntityManager` instance will become a bottleneck for more expensive operations. Both, from a memory perspective and also from a computational one. I assume the prolonged response times primarily stem from Hibernate applying dirty checks (i.e. checking all entity instances for potential changes made to them that would have to be flushed to the database) on the closure of the `EntityManager`.

### Potential solutions

#### Stick with `EntityManager.clear()`

While not necessarily the cleanest option, simply sticking to `EntityManager.clear()` might be a reasonable workaround, given that all others have broader impact, not only on the code that needs to be improved.

#### Switching to a different persistence approach for expensive operations

If you would still like to use Spring Boot's default approach, you could investigate whether there are ways to use alternative data access handling approaches for this particular operation. Can you avoid iterating over the initial result and triggering additional queries? Can you read results into (unmanaged) DTOs rather than (managed) entities? Does it make sense to use JPA native queries, or even a lower level API like jOOQ or JDBC?

#### Limit the scope of the `EntityManager`

A brute means to deal with this is to entirely take back the control of the `EntityManager` creation by setting the application configuration property `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false`. This will cause the `EntityManager` creation to be tied to the declaration of transactional boundaries (usually via `@Transactional`). Note, that this means that you'll *have to* consider this when scoping *all* data access, including other requests that fit the standard request model described above. A common strategy for this is annotating controllers or services with `@Transactional`. This can be further optimized for read-only scenarios by explicitly setting the `readOnly`-flag to `true`to configure Hibernate to skip the dirty checking completely.

A notable downside of this is that any response rendering outside such a transactional boundary that directly or indirectly triggers the resolution of JPA-lazy relationships will fail with a `LazyInitializationException` (except that relationship has been explicitly initialized within the transactional boundary). That approach imposing additional complexity and a significant intransparency (*"In which cases do I need to initialize which relationship?"*) is the primary reason for this approach not being the default for Spring Boot applications.

You could also try to find a middle ground by disabling the default registration of the `OSIVI`, and registering a `WebMvcConfigurer` that decorates an `OSIVI` interceptor with a `MappedInterceptor` to capture the include and exclude patterns suitable in your case.

#### Modelling your API to accommodate long-running actions

A final option is to design your HTTP resources and application state to accept the original request, turn the request into referable application state (i.e. calculate an identifier), return `202 Accepted` for that request. You could then asynchronously trigger the long-running functionality to eventually store the result under the identifier calculated originally. Clients would then issue a second request (the URI advertised via the `Location` header of the response to the original request) to obtain the result of that expensive computation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. In some cases I have already approached larger operations with unmanaged entities. I will have a look at the scope of the entityManager. I was not aware of such a functionality. In general i found the problem is managable as long as "it is thought about". Particularly new spring developers have issues with this that causes problems. It is nothing you see inside the code unless you know about it. However most interestingly would be the "dirty checks" you assume hibernate is doing. Do you have any idear how I could have a closer look at those? Or where to start looking?