# Efficiently Performing Bulk Updates with Spring Data JPA on a Large Number of Entities

Tags: java, spring, performance, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a large number of records that I need to update efficiently using Spring Data JPA. The records number in the thousands and my current approach of using a loop with the save() method is slow and inefficient. Can someone suggest a better way to perform bulk updates using Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy done by setting a property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=123
```

You will implement the updates/inserts in a loop but Hibernate will try to send them to the database in a batch.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t need to access the callback from your Repository you can simply Inject the bean `entityManager` and detatch from your Hibernate Context.

```
private final EntityManager entityManager;

public void someMethod(List<SomeObject> objects) {
    objects.forEach(someObject-> {
        res = someRepository.save(someObject);
        entityManager.detatch(res); // or use ´entityManager.clear();´ 
    });
}
```

This might also be useful ;)

[Why is JPA / Hibernate slowing down when loading a large amount of data in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75852833/why-is-jpa-hibernate-slowing-down-when-loading-a-large-amount-of-data-in-a-spr)